# Defining a git work flow for ZF applications

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-branch

I am new to git and there are a number of Zend Framework apps that I want to manage using git.

I've read that git is flexible and that you can create your own workflows. I have came up with following workflow but I am lost on how to implement this in git.

[image: Zf git Workflow]

There are mainly three repositories in this workflow, bare, development and production.

The bare repo will be cloned in my local machine. This bare repo will have two branches development and production.

If I make any changes and push the changes to development branch they will be committed to the development branch of the bare repo and then forwarded to development repo. The development repo will commit the changes and then push the files within the public folder to "www/app/dev" directory.

Similarly, if I push the master branch from my local machine, the changes will be committed to the master branch of the bare repo and then forwarded to production branch. The changes will be committed to the master branch of production repo and the files from the public directory will be copied to "www/app/prod" folder.

Also,

If either of the development or the production repositories are updated changes should be pushed back to the bare repo. I think this can be done using the post commit hook on both the repos.

I have tried many articles and creating update hooks but I've failed.

Can anyone please help me with this or guide me in the right direction?

This work flow is derived from the following workflow:

[Git Hub workflow](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/)

Comment: You probably don't want to be using a bare repo for programming on your local machine. The only difference between a bare and non-bare repo is that bare repos don't have a working copy/tree/directory of files...so if you want to make changes to code, you need a non-bare repo. Bare repos are only useful for backups or as remote repos, since those use-cases don't usually require an actual checkout of the files contained within the repo...though I suppose a non-bare remote repo can have useful applications as well.

Comment: @Cupcake In that case the bare repo can be a non bare.